# How to make a Samsung TV camera (Model VG-STC3000/ZA) work on xubuntu

Tags: camera, samsung

Sorry about this but I'm a "newbe" at this. Would not have bothered anyone but I have need of a webcam under the present global circumstances. The only one I have is this old one (SAMSUNG TV camera model VG-STC3000/ZA). I am GUESSING that drivers are missing or something but I have no idea how to solve the problem. I'm using ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS). When I use a webcam tester I get something about permissions not allowing the use of the webcam. Any help to make it work would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the VG STC family of cameras were custom-designed for Samsung TVs only. As such there is no official driver for Windows / Linux etc.

The closest I found when looking for the same problem is an unofficial windows driver located here:

https://github.com/Psypher9/VG-STC-Driver

Assuming that the driver is working, one could adapt that for a working linux driver. But that is not an easy task...